# nix-shell equivalent of `make -C DIR`?

Tags: nix

Is there a `nix-shell` equivalent to `make -C DIR`? Back before I had a Nix shell I used to run `sudo make -C ~/dev/root install` to configure my system, and with Nix shell I can't find any simpler way than `nix-shell --run 'sudo make -C ~/dev/root install' ~/dev/root/shell.nix` or `cd ~/dev/root && nix-shell --run 'sudo make install'` - if I try to simplify to `nix-shell --run 'sudo make -C ~/dev/root install'` it uses the shell.nix (or default.nix) in the current directory, and `nix-shell --run 'sudo make install' ~/dev/root/shell.nix` runs the inner `sudo make install` command within the current directory.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are trying to do. Are you trying to install software that you compile from source? In that case `make install` is the wrong way in the first place and you should write a derivation, put that into an overlay and install from that on your system. Nix shells are ephemeral so your dependencies that you compiled your program against will vanish at some point in time (unless you never collect garbage).

Comment: I'm not compiling anything. I'm just calling `make` within the Nix shell because the code still uses a Makefile to copy configuration.nix to /etc/nixos and run `nixos-rebuild`. But I think I understand - I should create an `install.nix` or default.nix` (or whatever an install file is called) and get rid of `make` completely.

Comment: Aha! That makes a lot more sense now, but wasn't clear from your question. You don't have to copy anything to `/etc/nixos`, that's just a convention, not a requirement. You can change the path to the configuration using the [`NIXOS_CONFIG`](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/92357f5e0b89f314c0edab52f04d9d9610b98155/nixos/doc/manual/man-nixos-rebuild.xml#L615-L626) environment variable, i.e. `NIXOS_CONFIG=/path/to/configuration.nix nixos-rebuild ...`

Comment: That's not what I'm asking, but that's an interesting fact in any case.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood it correctly when I paraphrase your question as

> How do I automatically `cd` to the path of `shell.nix` in a Nix shell?

A shell hook with `cd "${toString ./.}"` should do this trick.  This is of course totally impure. I also don't know what happens when `shell.nix` is a symlink. No refunds.

```
{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {} }:

pkgs.mkShell {
  buildInputs = [ pkgs.hello ];
  shellHook = ''cd "${toString ./.}"'';
}
```

```
$ nix-shell ~/Documents/letters/shell.nix --run "pwd"
/home/<user>/Documents/letters
```

Comment: Thank you! This will work, and I should've thought of it. I'm still hoping there's a solution which doesn't require handing this responsibility over to shell.nix.

Comment: @l0b0 Well, they are really two orthogonal things. After all you can always just use a subshell `(cd ~/dev/root && nix-shell --run 'sudo make install')`